# How to send cookies in websocket connection from extension's background script?

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, google-chrome-extension, websocket

I am trying to open an authenticated websocket connection to my backend from a chrome extension, for that I am using session cookies. This is my manifest file:

```json
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["extension.js"],
        "persistent": true
    },
    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "storage",
        "http://localhost:8000/",
        "ws://localhost:8000/"
    ],
    "icons": {
        "16": "img/icon16.png",
        "48": "img/icon48.png",
        "128": "img/icon128.png"
    }
}
```

there I asked permission to access `localhost:8000` on both HTTP and websocket schemes, but Chrome send cookies only for AJAX requests. If I try

```js
await fetch('http://localhost:8000/checklogin', {
    method: 'GET',
    credentials: 'include'
});
```

from background script cookies are sent, but if I try

```js
const ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8000/');
```

no cookies are sent at all.

Is not that same domain, why Chrome is not sending cookies for websocket?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my research I concluded CORS with credentials for websocket is not supported in chrome extensions, so Chrome won't inject credentials in websocket upgrade requests. A workaround for that is to use [chrome.webRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/webRequest/) to intercept websocket upgrade request and inject the `Cookie` header:

```js
class WebsocketCookie {

    constructor(websocketUrl, name, value) {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
        chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(
            ({ requestHeaders }) => {
                requestHeaders.push({name: 'Cookie', value: `${this.name}=${this.value}`});
                return {requestHeaders};
            },
            {types: ['websocket'], urls: [websocketUrl]},
            ['blocking', 'requestHeaders', 'extraHeaders']
        );
    }
}

// you can change this cookie later by changing cookie.name or cookie.value
const cookie = new WebsocketCookie('ws://localhost:8000/', 'sessionid', 'my_session_id');
const ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8000/'); // sessionid cookie will be injected
```

that requires websocket URL, `webRequest` and the `webRequestBlocking` permissions to be added to manifest file. Use [chrome.cookies](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/cookies/) to get cookies you need to inject in websocket upgrade request.

If you would like to improve security, [onBeforeSendHeaders](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/webRequest/#event-onBeforeSendHeaders) callback takes the origin of that request as `initiator` member, use that to check if origin is your own extension. You can get your extension's origin using [chrome.management](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/management/#method-getSelf) API.

Comment: For me, it's not working. Pushing non cookie header can work while pushing cookie header will not work.